# Preloading entities with EF4

Tags: entity-framework

I have a bunch of classificators which will be used quite often. I wan't to preload those entities when my program starts so that I wouldn't have to do it later when any object references them.

How can this be done in EF4?

Comment: What is wrong on executing the query when program starts and store entities in some global accessible collection?

Comment: how should it look then?

Answer (score 1):

There's a long-ish walkthrough here:

[How to Cache Entity Framework Reference Data](https://web.archive.org/web/20150625081829/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/22/tip-14-caching-entity-framework-reference-data.aspx)

But profile first. Writing good [projections](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502174052/http://blogs.teamb.com:80/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500) may be faster than materializing entire entities with cached references. Even loading single referenced objects is quite fast. Don't "optimize" stuff which isn't slow.